# How to redirect in ASP.NET based on URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, windows-server-2008

How can I redirect user based on host in aspx page?
For example, I want redirect user to localhost99.com if url is host22.com and redirect to host22.com if url is localhost99.com

I tried out something like this:

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.ServerVariables["SCRIPT_NAME"] + "?" + Request.ServerVariables["QUERY_STRING"] != "host22.com/default.aspx") 
        {
            Response.Redirect("http://localhost99.com/");
        }
    }
```

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably have better success doing this upstream in the request handling pipeline.  Check out the possibility of inserting an http handler module in your application.